# Create an index column by groups of date and id

Tags: r, indexing, group-by, dplyr

R / Stackoverflow newbie here.

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
    year mother_id   nest_seq incubation_date
   <int> <chr>          <int> <date>         
 1  1994 543762-MMM         1 1994-10-16     
 2  1994 543762-MMM         3 1994-11-06     
 3  1994 543762-MMM         4 1994-11-24     
 4  1994 543762-MMM         6 1994-12-05     
 5  1995 583809-mGMW        4 1994-10-24     
 6  1995 583809-mGMW        7 1994-11-21     
 7  1995 583809-mGMW        8 1994-12-22     
 8  1996 596751-BWM         1 1994-11-20     
 9  1996 596751-BWM         2 1994-12-23     
10  1996 626691-GBW         2 1994-11-08
```

I simply want to generate a new `nest_seq` based on the `incubation_date` For example:

```
 year mother_id   nest_seq incubation_date new_nest_seq
   <int> <chr>          <int> <date>         <int>
 1  1994 543762-MMM         1 1994-10-16        1
 2  1994 543762-MMM         3 1994-11-06        2
 3  1994 543762-MMM         4 1994-11-24        3
 4  1994 543762-MMM         6 1994-12-05        4
```

I have been trying to do this using `if_else()` but getting stuck...

```
group_by(year, mother_id) %>%
mutate(new_nest_seq = if_else(min(incubation_date), 1, ?)))
```

Would greatly appreciate any advice...

Comment: R for data science (available online as a website) has a chapter on the lubridate package from memory - that could be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  # Just in case: order 
  arrange(year, mother_id, incubation_date) %>% 
  group_by(year, mother_id) %>%
  # Create new index
  mutate(
    new_nest_seq = 1, 
    new_nest_seq = cumsum(new_nest_seq)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>     year mother_id   nest_seq incubation_date new_nest_seq
#>    <int> <fct>          <int> <fct>                  <dbl>
#>  1  1994 543762-MMM         1 1994-10-16                 1
#>  2  1994 543762-MMM         3 1994-11-06                 2
#>  3  1994 543762-MMM         4 1994-11-24                 3
#>  4  1994 543762-MMM         6 1994-12-05                 4
#>  5  1995 583809-mGMW        4 1994-10-24                 1
#>  6  1995 583809-mGMW        7 1994-11-21                 2
#>  7  1995 583809-mGMW        8 1994-12-22                 3
#>  8  1996 596751-BWM         1 1994-11-20                 1
#>  9  1996 596751-BWM         2 1994-12-23                 2
#> 10  1996 626691-GBW         2 1994-11-08                 1
```

#### Or via `dplyr::row_number`:

```r
df %>%
  # Just in case: order 
  arrange(year, mother_id, incubation_date) %>% 
  group_by(year, mother_id) %>%
  # Create new index
  mutate(new_nest_seq = dplyr::row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @stefan, This does exactly what I needed.

Comment: My pleausre. BTW: You could also use `mutate(new_nest_seq = dplyr::row_number())`. Added this as a second solution. And if you want do me a favor: Mark the question as answered. Besides giving me some credit it shows others with a similar problem that the solution worked and removes the question from the queue of questions still waiting for an answer.